# Is "censer" common?

Tags: vocabulaire

"To be supposed to do something" is very very common in English. And until now I didn't know there was a good translation for it until I just came across this--- *Je suis censé arriver à 6h.*

Why haven't I come across this more often? Is it not as common as the English translation? Is it formal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Censé vs supposé](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14198/cens%c3%a9-vs-suppos%c3%a9)

Comment: This question is from 9 years ago :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *censer* is obsolete and you won't find it in day-to-day use. Only the past participle of *censer* → **censé** is commonly used.

From my experience as a native (Swiss) French speaker, **censé faire quelque chose** is as common as the English locution *to be supposed to do something*. There is nothing formal about it.

See [Le Trésor de la langue française informatisé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cens%C3%A9).

Answer (score 1):

I hear its past participle used in negative constructions quite often when my French wife lets me know that I have done/am doing something that I shouldn’t:

> T’es/étais même pas censé le faire !

Or else when I’ve done/am doing something incorrectly:

> T’es/étais pas censé (le) faire comme ça !

Except to the extent that she usually says these things while she’s “formally” reading me the “Riot Act,” I’d agree with Pierre Arnaud that there’s nothing formal about it, neither in its negative nor its affirmative form.

As an aside, I'll add that the false friends/cognates, *sense* and *censé*, at least in my two negative examples, help me to get what she probably really means:

> You don't have enough *sense* to know how to do it (correctly)!