# Censé vs supposé

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

To translate the idea of

> I am supposed to do something

What is the difference between saying

> Je suis censé faire quelque chose

as opposed to

> Je suis supposé faire quelque chose

Is there any difference in meaning or connotation?

Comment: I thought both were synonyms, but I doubt since I refered to my dictionary. I think their meaning is close but not necessarily the same (supposition vs expectation). *Censé* is surely a good choice. *Supposé* is probably good too, but the meaning might be a bit different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that, while it is used (especially in Québec), "*Je suis supposé faire quelque chose*" is a a calque of the English phrase. Orally, there is not really any difference between the two, but for proper written French, you should use "*Je suis censé faire quelque chose*" or "*Je dois faire quelque chose*".

> **Être supposé de**
>
> On peut remplacer ce calque provenant de *to be supposed to* par **être censé, devoir** ou faire débuter la phrase par **normalement, en principe, il est convenu que** (suivi de l’indicatif ou de l’impersonnel), etc. : *Il est convenu que je partirai ce soir* (au lieu de *Je suis supposé…*). *J’étais censée/je devais me présenter à l’entrevue hier. En principe, j’ai une entrevue demain.*
>
> [TERMIUM Plus](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=9ogdJW_EEkkM.html#zz9ogdJW_EEkkM)

Comment: It's funny, because *calque* itself is a loanword from French.

Comment: And moreover, *"suppose"* is coming from French verb *"supposer"* ;)

Comment: Yes, the etymology is right https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suppose#Etymology

But still, it doesn't have the exactly same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to this [other answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14199), where we're presented with the influence of "*to be supposed to*" on "*être supposé de*"; in the *DHLF* we also have:

> ♦ Le passif être supposé s'emploie avec l'infinitif, pour « être censé
>   », par influence de l'anglais. Être supposé de (et infinitif) existe
>   en français du Québec.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous dir. A. Rey,
>   ed. *Le Robert* - *supposer* ]

If I understand correctly, this influence and meaning is not restricted to Québec insofar as we're talking about the form with no "*de*". There is a subtle difference between "*je suis supposé faire quelque chose*" and "*je suis supposé de faire quelque chose*", the latter not unlike the rare construction "*censé de* + infinitive" (see "rem. a)" [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cens%C3%A9)). But you do not allude to this form.

Whereas *Termium* discusses the *calque* and offers some replacement solutions covering both the normative as well as the expectation [sense](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/suppose), the same can't be said of the *BDL/GDT*. They have an entry for [*supposément*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2791) (which has a similar sort of influence from *supposedly*)<sup>1</sup>, but have left out "*être supposé*". They discuss "[*censé*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=cens%C3%A9&T3.x=0&T3.y=0)" only being constructed with "*être*" and followed with an infinitive verb, and meaning basically *estimated/expected* (see [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cens%C3%A9)). The surprising [*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/to-be-supposed-to-do-sth) seemingly introduces a variation in the translation based on intensity i.e. *required/expected to*.

What will happen of this [influence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je%20suis%20suppos%C3%A9%2Csuppos%C3%A9ment%2Cje%20suis%20cens%C3%A9&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20suppos%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppos%C3%A9ment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20cens%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) is uncertain but having "*supposément*" around in Québec surely makes the construction more usual there; different strokes for different folks. Something with the passive voice is cumbersome with either of *censé/supposé* and the preferred active voice with a verb such as "*devoir*", which is semantically more straightforward, trumps them both when writing in my opinion. But like both *Termium* and the *BDL* explain, there is value in accuracy, as well as in variety.

---

<sub>1. It should be noted that "[*supposément*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suppos%C3%A9ment)" (1971, DHLF/Rey) has been in use for more than [50 years](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=95XeuJeF5Q5I.html#zz95XeuJeF5Q5I) in Québec, despite having been sharply [criticized](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=93yR9LoIHSVs.html#zz93yR9LoIHSVs) initially; it now appears in the *TLFi*. Another example where opinions differ was that of the *green thumb*: [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=GREEN%20THUMB), [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8399282), [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vert)).</sub>